# openvswitch stt and geneve

Tags: tunnel, openvswitch

The openvswitch 2.4 states that it has support for STT and Geneve tunneling but I do not see any example/sample that shows the configuration commands.

For GRE/VXLAN: http://networkstatic.net/configuring-vxlan-and-gre-tunnels-on-openvswitch/ or http://www.ran-lifshitz.com/2014/08/24/tunneling-and-network-virtualization-nvgre-vxlan/

For STT : ??
For Geneve : ??

Can someone please provide the configuration details for stt/geneve on openvswitch ?

Thanks

PS: Newbie here, please point me to the right answer if this question has already been asked/answered although I did try to find before posting.

Answer (score 1):

Here is tutorial that explains how to set up GRE tunneling - http://openvswitch.org/support/config-cookbooks/port-tunneling/.

Once you have verified that GRE works in your environment simply change `type` column in `Interface` table for the respective tunnel Interface to STT or Geneve method:

```
ovs-vsctl set Interface theTunnelInterface type=stt
```

To use STT or Geneve you also need to make sure that you have the right kernel module loaded that supports particular tunneling method. This is the reason I would suggest you to get GRE working first and then change to STT or Geneve.